# NFC C# library for windows

Tags: c#, windows, nfc

How can I write a program in c# on Windows that can read and write to NFC cards?. Open source / commercial are both fine. Thanks

Comment: reworded to be more problem solving as I'd like to know how to read and write NFC cards in C# at all

Comment: Also, whoever closed this was an idiot.

Comment: Any chance that the situation has changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contact Stollmann: http://www.stollmann.de/en/home and ask for the Windows NFC stack or the windows NFC Dev-Kit.

**Disclaimer**: I work for stollmann, and I'm one of the engineers who did the NFC on Android, Windows and Linux (and more) platform solution. Yes, I promote my own product here.. Otoh as far as I know it's the only product out there that offers modern NFC-functionality on the Windows platform.

Comment: Is the development kit something that you offer for free, or is there a cost associated with it?

Comment: I don't know, (I'm not into sales, I'm an engineer). I suggest that you just drop an email, explain what you want to do, you situation (e.g. dude at a company versus student interested in NFC) and ask for a demo/eval package.

Comment: websites is down. maybe the company is closed and you still have the code and can open source the nfc stack. i am looking for nfc of PN532 for dot net to initiate bluetooth handshake

Comment: They went out of business a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're going to have to write your own stack. You'll have to send, receive and process reader and tag specific commands. Best to start with the ACR122U NFC reader. It's cheap, has good documentation is is fully NFC compatible.

Comment: The ACR122U reader is a good starter NFC reader, but it certainly is not the best. It has an old NXP chip in it; the NXP 533 is the latest NXP NFC chip.

Answer (score 2):

[GoToTags](https://gototags.com/) has both a [.NET NFC SDK](https://gototags.com/net-sdk/) and a [Windows NFC App](https://gototags.com/windows-app/). Windows 8 has built in support for NFC, although it doesn't cover the full stack of what you will likely need for an application.

A related note, if you are looking for a Windows-based SDK there is a big difference between the PC/SC (smart card) based SDKs and the native SDKs. Using PC/SC with NFC is a bit of a hack; it works for the basic tag reading and writing, but since you do not have direct access to the NFC controller and chip you will be unable to do any of the more advanced NFC functions such as P2P. Also the PC/SC stack is useless if you need to do high-speed reading or encoding of NFC tags.

DISCLAIMER: I am the CEO of GoToTags

Comment: I'm currently developing a web application. I would like to allow users to login on my web using NFC card, is that possible with your SDK?

Comment: I don't see any .NET NFC SDK - page is not found. Please correct or remove your answer if you stopped providing SDK.

Comment: @craig.tadlock your link to the .net sdk is broken

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something in Python and came across this:

- https://launchpad.net/nfcpy

Looks relatively easy to get started too, unlike the bit-twiddling code I've seen in other places.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools). Based on the same project, I have created an [NFC Eclipse Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) with an NDEF message editor, if that is your game.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for, but have you tried libnfc? http://www.libnfc.org
It is in C by the way.